# How can I enable a HTTPS connection on my Mac OS?

Tags: macos, https, connection, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application on my Mac OS with "Snow Leopard" 10.6.5 and for this I need to use locally a **Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure** (HTTPS) connection.

How can I set my machine to do that? What I have to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using the built-in web server enabled when you "enable web sharing".  That server is Apache, so google for "enable SSL in Apache".

Short form is that it's easy to do but you need a an x509 certificate, a "cert"; a self-generated cert will work but you'll have to tell your browser to trust it.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I last set up my server, I found Apple´s documentation to be very helpful:

http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html

Comment: I already made that. Now I have to use that with my Ruby on Rails 3 applications.

Comment: This might help (scroll down until the ruby action starts):    http://andyjeffries.co.uk/articles/x509-encrypted-authenticated-socket-ruby-client